# Reset CSS - Set padding and margin to 0?

Tags: css, reset

Looking at [YUI 2: Reset CSS](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/) they set `margin:0` and `padding:0` on multiple elements. I don't care about IE6 or IE7 on my pages. Will I still need to set `margin:0` for each element anyway?

- div (no)
- ol (yes)
- ul (yes)
- li (no)
- form (only IE6,IE7)
- input (no)
- textarea (no)

Will I still need to set `padding:0` for each element anyway?

- body (no)
- div (no)
- ul (yes)
- ol (yes)
- li (no)
- form (no)
- textarea (yes)
- p (no)

Will still I need to set `border:0` for image?

A: Only for linked images

Anything else you recomend?

Comment: I don't get your question. Are you using a reset CSS? Does this CSS set `margin: 0` and `padding: 0` to all element (I suppose, yes)? If so, why are you asking if you have to re-do it?

Comment: Sorry for not beeing clear... I am not using any CSS reset code, I figure I might set the style when styleing the element. So the question is really: Will I need to set maring:0 to make the element compatible in every modern browser (id don't have IE 8 so I can't test).

Comment: The time required to do this is not really worth the benefit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look up IE’s built-in style sheets on this website: http://www.iecss.com/

It has links to styles of Firefox, WebKit and Opera. You could cross-reference these to make a decision.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you want the margin and padding on elements on your page to be a particular value. If it doesn't matter then by all means leave it as the browser default- just don't rely on it because there's no guarantee that all the browsers in the world will use the default that your testing browser does. I would recommend that you customise [normalize.css](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css) and use it in your code. If you're bothered about having to load another stylesheet, or bloating your own stylesheet, you can always [compress the CSS](http://www.refresh-sf.com/yui/) and paste it onto a line at the top of your file.

Answer (score 0):

It's not something related to *browser element compatibility*. All standard elements are *compatible* (i.e. displayed for what they are) in every browser.

The problem is that usually browsers apply default styling properties for some elements in different ways. For example, IE and Firefox apply a different default margin for block elements, a different font size for headings (h1, h2, ...), etc...

CSS Reset style sheets help you to **remove all these inconsistencies** by **flattening all styles** that can be different in different browsers.

You can read an article here:

> http://sixrevisions.com/css/css-tips/css-tip-1-resetting-your-styles-with-css-reset/

Answer (score 0):

I **always** use this one:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        outline: 0;
        font-size: 100%;
        vertical-align: baseline;
        background: transparent;
}
body {
        line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
        list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
        quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
        content: '';
        content: none;
}

/* remember to define focus styles! */
:focus {
        outline: 0;
}

/* remember to highlight inserts somehow! */
ins {
        text-decoration: none;
}
del {
        text-decoration: line-through;
}

/* tables still need 'cellspacing="0"' in the markup */
table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0;
}
```